# Hide a div id/class if the value of an input id is empty

Tags: html, hide

In my options panel I have a section where the user can enter their Twitter username. Currently, if the value for that field is empty, the Twitter icon still appears on my website and I want it to not be there if the value is empty.

Say if my div class that makes the Twitter icon appear is called '.twitter' how would I hide this if the value of the input id called 'mytheme_twitter' is empty?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#mytheme_twitter:empty')){$('.twitter').hide();}
```

If you have multiple twitter classes this will hide them all. otherwise you would need a selector for which twitter class you want to hide.

Comment: This works but when I enter a username so it's no longer empty, the div stays hidden. Am I missing something?

Comment: hmm.... try 
$(document).ready(function(){
if(!$('#mytheme_twitter:empty')){
$('.twitter').show();
}
});